# Conditions for a node to be a leaf node on DFS tree

Tags: trees, graph-traversal

Question:
Consider the DFS tree generated by a DFS on a connected graph. Write below the necessary and sufficient condition for a node v to be a leaf node on the DFS tree. The condition must be in term's of v's discovery time d[v] and finishing time f[v].

---

I honestly have no idea what the answer to this question from a past exam may be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node v is a leaf node on the DFS tree if and only if f[v] = d[v] + 1.

The proof is obvious once you follow the DFS, marking each node's discovery time and finishing time. A leaf is defined as a node that has no children. 
Let $v$ be a node.

- Suppose $v$ has children in the final DFS tree. That is, we will go forward to a child $u$ of $v$ right after we have discovered $v$. That is, $d[v]+1 = d[u]$. The finishing time of $v$ must come after that. So f[v] $\gt$ d[v] + 1.
- Suppose $v$ has no children in the final DFS tree. That is, we will go backtracking once we have discovered $v$. That is, we will finish $v$ right after we have discovered it. That is,  f[v] = d[v] + 1.

For people who are not familiar with discovery time and finishing time of a node v associated to a DFS, you can check either [Stanford course note](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1166/lectures/lecture10.pdf) or [Carnegie Mellon course note](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15210/recitations/graph-search.pdf). Of course, you may just search by yourself.